# Finding the expectation and variance from a probability generating function

Tags: probability, expected-value, generating-functions, variance

> For the probability generating function $G_X(z) = \frac{p}{1-qz}$
> where $q=1-p$, use $G_X(z)$ to deduce that
> $$E[X] = \frac{1-p}{p}\quad \text{ and } \quad Var(X) = \frac{1-p}{p^2}$$

Do I need to differentiate with respect to $z$ for the expectation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you need to differentiate with respect to $z$ and evaluate at $z=1$. Specifically $$G'(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{p}{1-qz}\right)=\frac{pq}{(1-qz)^2}$$ and so at $z=1$ $$E[X]=G'(1)=\frac{pq}{(1-q)^2}=\frac{p(1-p)}{p^2}=\frac{1-p}{p}$$ Now the variance is given by $$Var(X)=G''(1)+G'(1)-[G'(1)]^2$$ Can you take it from here? For more details, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Probabilities_and_expectations) (note also the notation $1^-$ instead of $1$).

Comment: Brilliant, thank-you very much for your help!

Comment: @user3199301 I confused $p$ and $q$. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just needed that push in the right direction :).